# In Spider-Man: Homecoming, why is Bruce Banner's picture on the wall along with other very famous scientists?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, spider-man-homecoming

As can be seen in the following picture from Spider-Man: Homecoming, Bruce Banner's pic is on the wall in Peter Parker's school along with other very famous scientists including Albert Einstein, Isaac Newton, Nikola Tesla, Marie Curie, Niels Bohr, Galileo Galilei and others.

[image: Image showing Bruce Banner on a wall of portraits alongside Einstein Tesla and other great scientists]

All of them have made significant contributions in science and the more recent ones have won Nobel Prizes (Curie actually won 2!).

We know Banner is brilliant but as far as I can tell he's not up to the caliber of the other people in the pic or at least we haven't been told if he is recognized as such by the scientific community in the MCU by having received prizes, awards or making some very important discovery.

So my question is: **What has Banner done to earn his place in the "wall of fame" in the school along with the other renowned scientists?**

[image: (part of screencap with scientists cut and shown full size)]

Comment: Maybe it's because he's an Avenger. Or maybe Peter sneakily put it there. Or maybe it's an easter egg :D

Comment: Probably the same reason Stan Lee is always hanging around doing random jobs in the background.

Comment: Wow! Great that you noticed that. BTW, he is a top-notch nuclear physicist in line with Stephen Hawkings. Stephen Hawkings is also not a noble prize winner, but he is considered more intelligent than Einstein.

Comment: @Moogle Stan Lee isn't doing "random" jobs, his entire plot-line is tied together.

Comment: @Bat Stephen isn't on the wall.

Comment: Just a Easter egg like picture of Abraham Erskine and Howard Stark we see in same film.

Comment: @Bat Hawking has made very important contributions in the study of black holes and Hawking radiation etc with a career spanning decades unlike Banner. Btw, he's not a nuclear physicist and furthermore he's not in the pic ;-)

Comment: Banner might have done something more important than Hawking. Afterall, SHIELD consults Banner, not Hawking or Jane (Noble Prize winner)..

Comment: @AnkitSharma I wonder why Hank Pym isn't in the list..

Comment: @Bat maybe because he is less established then Stark and Banner in films

Comment: Maybe it is because he has so many PhDs. https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/176889/1148

Comment: Hulk not smash school with picture on wall

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Bruce Banner is the renowned scientist with a genius level intellect and he apparently holds several PhDs (7 to be exact ***as mentioned in Thor: Ragnarok***) in various fields like ***Biochemistry***, ***Nuclear Physics***, ***Gamma radiation*** and few others (mentioned [here](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Hulk)).

It is also worth noting that he "almost" re-created the super-soldier serum that made Captain America. To quote his abilities from [here](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Bruce_Banner_(Earth-616)),

> Doctor Bruce Banner is a super-genius in nuclear physics, possessing a mind so brilliant that it cannot be measured by any known intelligence test.

Also as mentioned [here](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Bruce_Banner_(Earth-616))

> After joining S.H.I.E.L.D., Banner was able to build new technologies
>   to help mankind:
>
> - Banner has created a purification unit that could prevent all    waterborne disasters for the next five years.
> - Banner has made the catalytic converter, which could save countless from smoking induced cancers.
> - Banner has designed a suit of his own, but it's maximum    capabilities are unknown. Since unlike the Hulk Banner can't breath underwater, the suit enables Banner to breath on oxygen-less environments. The suit also allows him to survive absolute zero temperatures.
> - Banner also has constructed a contact lens which allows    him to operate it like a computer.

Maybe if he wans't bouncing around as the Hulk, he would have achieved far more than what we saw.

By looking at his feats, it is quite obvious that he is comparable with the greatest minds of our time like Stephen Hawking, Albert Einstein and many others.

**PS**: Or maybe the MCU just wanted to put an Easter egg for the fans!

Comment: are any of the above true statements in the MCU about which this question is asked?

Comment: @NKCampbell The points about him having those PhDs, recreating the super-soldier serum. This link: http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Hulk also mentions how Phil Coulson calls Banner (with his genius level intellect) as an equal to Hawking.

Comment: "Banner has made the catalytic converter, which could save countless from smoking induced cancers." Well, the [catalytic converter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalytic_converter) was invented in the 1950s, but applied to exhausts and not cigarettes. Unfortunate naming there.

Comment: @Ellesedil well, i'm not making stuff up. You can check those inventions of his in the link i've provided. its funny though, how they've used that name

Comment: @Shreedhar Yet somehow Prof. Hawking is **not** on that wall, nor is anyone else still alive for that matter. While the out-of-universe reason may just be copyright issues with pictures of living scientists (maybe they would have to be paid residuals in those cases), it is still weird that not even the original inventor of the super-soldier serum is up there, Dr. Erskine, who after all worked in New York. The two times Bruce was in New York, he ripped part of it (Haarlem in his fight with the Abomination and Manhattan while fighting the Chitauri) apart.

Comment: @BMWurm I totally agree with you. Maybe its just nothing more than an easter egg and we are actually over-thinking it :P

Comment: I mean, he *did* successfully conduct an experiment that turned an ordinary human into a superhero. It wasn’t directly reproducible at the time, but that’s still quite the scientific achievement. I’d consider someone for the Nobel prize for something like that, that’s for sure.

Answer (score 2):

He may or may not have contributed as much to science in the MCU as the other scientists pictured, but he did help save the world, twice, and saved Harlem from the Abomination.

If you’re trying to get children interested in science, it probably helps to have a really famous hero in your list of scientists.

Answer (score -5):

Bruce Banner was the foremost leading scientist an expert on the subject of gamma radiation. He is to gamma radiation what Newton was to gravity.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/119617)

Comment: While length of this answer leaves much to be desired, it could be salvaged with addition of relevant quotes.

Comment: This answer is not delete worthy. It provides an answer to the question regardless of the fact that it doesn't have a source. @TimSparrow care to clarify how this doesn't answer the question? From what I can see it it answers it as good as any other answer would, just doesn't provide evidence..

Comment: I think it answer s the question,but in such minimal way that it does not show the quality I have come to appreciate about this site.